# UIImageView not seen after adding to subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to create Views w.r.t the `JSON` data.There is Tag in `JSON` data called "type"

```
{                    
   "type"=text; 
};
       OR 
{
   "type"=image;
};
```

And I will created array of type details and from that array creating views.**

```
float y=10;
 for(ViewTypes *type in TypeArray )
{
  if ([type.typeString isEqualToString:@"image"])
{
      NSlog(@"image view is added");       
      UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init ]; 
      imageView.frame=CGRectMake(55, y, 150, 5);
      imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
      [CustomView addSubview:imageView];

      y+=10;

   }
       else if ([type.typeString isEqualToString:@"text"]){
       NSlog(@"text view is added");       
       UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]init ]; 
       textView.frame=CGRectMake(55, y, 150, 5);
       textView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
       [CustomView addSubview: textView];

       y+=10;
 }
 }

`loop` and if-else  is working fine ,But only `UITextView` is seen in the view and not the `UIImageView`.
```

Comment: Set image in UIImageView first then check.

Comment: add breakpoint to  [CustomView addSubview:imageView]; to see if it's getting executed

Comment: I set backgroundColor in the view

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty I already checked its fine,and checked with  [CustomView subViews] .the view is in the customeView.

Comment: Then add an image to your uiimageview to see if the image appears or not. You may comment the textField addition also, probably the UIImageView is too small

Comment: Friends early I testing with simulator ,But now I tested with device the code is working !!!and all view are seen .For conformation I again    run my code in simulator image view is not displaying .

Comment: Check whether the CustomView added  as subView ,and check the CustomView frame.

Answer (score 0):

Add `UIImage` in `UIImageView` to show it.

```
if ([type.typeString isEqualToString:@"image"]){
   NSlog(@"image view is added");       
  UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init ]; 
         imageView.frame=CGRectMake(55, y, 150, 5);
         imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
         **[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"imagename.png"]];**
         [CustomView addSubview:imageView];
 y+=10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 float y=10;
 for(ViewTypes *type in TypeArray ){

  if ([type.typeString isEqualToString:@"image"]){

        NSlog(@"image view is added");       
      UIImageView *imageView=[[UIImageView alloc]init ]; 
             imageView.frame=CGRectMake(55, y, 150, 5);
             imageView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
             [CustomView addSubview:imageView];
             [CustomView bringSubviewToFront:imageView];

     y+=10;

   }else if ([type.typeString isEqualToString:@"text"]){
       NSlog(@"text view is added");       
       UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]init ]; 
             textView.frame=CGRectMake(55, y, 150, 5);
             textView.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
             [CustomView addSubview: textView];
    y+=10;
 }}
```

Comment: ok.. please change the bg color of your custom view to check whether the customview size is larger than the subview size..

Comment: also just disable the auto layout and try.. if it work properly, then the issue is related to the auto layout an constraints.. so you can solve it by adding proper constraints to your subviews

Comment: ref : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636305/how-to-auto-layout-with-existing-custom-view-with-multiple-subviews-in-ios-6

Comment: when my code run in simulator this problem occurs but in device it work fine what may be the reason??

Comment: which simulator and device you are using ?  6 or 6 plus ??